# C++ unwanted change in struct variable even when not passing by reference

Tags: c++, reference

I am passing a variable of type AST into function substitute, which then is changed due to unknown reasons, below is the code.

This substitute function changes each non-boolean variable in the AST to a boolean value, and somehow the original AST is changed even after this function is executed in the main function, I don't want AST original to change, please help!! sorry if my code indentation is weird.

```
    struct AST {std::string info; pNODE children[2]; };

    void subHelper (AST *T, string a, string b){
      if (T->children[0]==NULL&&T->children[1]==NULL){
       if (T->info.compare(a)==0)
       {
      T->info = b;
        }
      return;
      }
      if (T->children[0]!=NULL){
          subHelper((T->children[0]), a,b);
       }
      if (T->children[1]!=NULL)
          subHelper((T->children[1]), a,b);
       }

    AST substitute(list<bool> vals, list<string> vars, AST original)
    {
     int a = vals.size();
      int b = vars.size();
        if (a==b)
    {
       //cout<<"\n";
        //prinTree(original);
      //cout<<"\n";
     //attempt of trying to save original by copying it
     AST value;
      value.info=original.info;
      value.children[0]=original.children[0];
       value.children[1]=original.children[1];
     for (it2 = vals.begin(), it=vars.begin(); it2 != vals.end(); it++, 
      it2++)
        {
       if(*it2 == false)
       {
         subHelper(&value, *it, "F");
        }
       else
       {
      subHelper(&value, *it, "T");
       }
      }
    // prinTree(Exp);cout<<"\n";
     //prinTree(value);cout<<"\n";
     return value;
    }
    else 
   {
     return original;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Try adding const like this void subHelper (const AST *T, string a, string b){

Comment: I suggest you take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). With a debugger you can not only catch crashes, or step through your code line by line (the last of which might help you here) but also set *watch-points* that breaks execution when a variable changes value. If you do that then you will easily find when and where your data changes.

Comment: Also regarding the comment "attempt of trying to save original by copying it", it seems that `children` is an array of *pointers*. You only copy the *pointers* and not what they point to with the assignments. That is, you now have *two* pointers pointing to the same memory (e.g. `value.children[0]` and `original.children[0]` are both pointing to the same data).

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Which value in the original struct are you claiming was changed? Was it `info`, `children[0]` or `children[1]`? What was the previous value? What was the new value?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your children array holds pointers, so your value copy is a shallow copy rather than a deep copy of original - at deeper levels of the tree, they remain the same, so changes reflect to both.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys thanks for pointing out my mistake, here is my attempt at deep copy, it seems to work.

```
void deepcopy(AST *dest, AST *source){
  if (source->children[0]==NULL&&source->children[1]==NULL){
    dest->info=source->info;
    return;
  }
  dest->info=source->info;
  AST *node = new AST();
  if (source->children[0]!=NULL){
    dest->children[0]=node;
    deepcopy((dest->children[0]), source->children[0]);
  }
 if (source->children[1]!=NULL){
    dest->children[1]=node;
    deepcopy((dest->children[1]), source->children[1]);
 }
}
```

Comment: nvm I fixed it, was just calling it wrongly, THANKS ALOT!! spent so much time on this and I couldnt even realize that my attempt at deep copy was pathetic haha xd.